# Can't seem to see variables and use them from Python IDLE shell after running main

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a newbie to python...I am running Python 3.6.4 IDLE and Windows 10....When I run the following code all works well (ie...from IDLE I press F5)...After shell opens and displays 'Resource created' I would like to then use this resource and enter commands at the shell.....However when I type 'm' at the command prompt in the shell I receive the following error:  Can someone please help me on this?

```
Resource created
>>> m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    m
NameError: name 'm' is not defined
```

BK_Logger.py

```
import visa

class BK_scpi():

    def __init__(self, filename, resource):
        '''Initialize class routine'''
        self.filename = filename
        self.resource = resource
        self.logfile = ''
        self.equip = ''
        self.command = ''
        self.value = 0

    def CreateResource(self):
        '''create USBTMC resource'''
        self.equip = visa.ResourceManager()
        self.resource = self.equip.open_resource('USB0::0x2EC7::0x8800::602197010727630104::INSTR')
        print ('Resource created')
        return (self.resource)
```

main.py

```
from BK_Logger import BK_scpi

def main():
    bk = BK_scpi('TadiranTLH5930', 'bk')

    m = bk.CreateResource()

main()
```

Comment: `m` is a *local* variable in the `main()` function. Local variables are cleaned up when the function where they were defined exits. `m` is no longer available. If you need it elsewhere, use a `return m` statement to pass it to the caller of the function. Then call the function from IDLE, or change the call to `main()` to assign the returned value to a global variable.

Comment: The error would be the same however you edit and run your code, for the reason Martijn explained.